Exception is not propagated when task fails in asyncio while using workers
I have an asyncio code where I create a queue with async tasks to be processed, create a list of workers to work on these tasks and await for the queue to be emptied to gather the results.
The simplified code looks something like this:
import asyncio

async def task():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
    raise Exception('task is corrupted') # scenario when time-taking process raised an exception
    print('task completed')


async def worker(queue):
    while not queue.empty():
        t = await queue.get() # get the task
        await t
        queue.task_done() # mark the task as done
    asyncio.current_task().cancel() # when are tasks are done, cancel itself

async def func():
    try:
        queue = asyncio.Queue()

        await queue.put(task()) # add tasks (in this case - one task)

        workers=[]
        workers.append(asyncio.create_task(worker(queue))) # add workers (in this case - one worker)

        await queue.join() # wait for the queue to be completed
        print('tasks execution completed')
    except Exception as err:
        raise Exception('tasks execution did not complete')

asyncio.run(func())

The issue with this code is that when there is no exception in task, it works:
>>> asyncio.run(func())
task completed
tasks execution completed

But if the exception is raised, it is not getting catched by the try-except block in func() and it runs indefinitely.
I tried to wrap worker in try-except:
async def worker(queue):
    try:
        while not queue.empty():
            t = await queue.get()
            await t
            queue.task_done()
    except Exception as err:
        raise Exception('worker failed') from err
    finally:
        asyncio.current_task().cancel()

with no result - queue is still waiting for completion, despite the exception.
How can overcome it? Is this code incorrectly designed?

The design looks overly complicated to me, in any case you are missing to await on the task created with asyncio.create_task(worker(queue)) somewhere.

The idea of the queue and workers is to balance the server load. The task itself send a request to API, and the ammout of tasks is huge. I have specified the amount of workers and the queue so that the tasks are accumulated in the FIFO list and gradually processed by concurrent workers. Do I need to await the workers if the tasks queue completion implicates they are already canceled? Why the exception isn't taken into account in func?
